# filter python requests result

Tags: python, filter, output

I am new to Python and am using requests to extract data from an API and now I want to sum only certain values from the output:

```
import requests
import json

url = "APIlink"

payload={}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer '+accesstoken
}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
output = response.json()
```

When I print output I get a result looking like this:

```
[{'id': 1, 'capacity': 5}, {'id': 2, 'capacity': 31}]
```

How can I filter only the capacity?
And how can I sum all the capacity to 36?

I tried something like print(output[0].capacity) to test how I would do this, but then I get the following:

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'capacity'
Does this mean that it is still no JSON output?

I am probably missing something really basic...

Comment: You need to understand the type of the response you are getting. output is a python list which contains python dictionaries. You could access capacity like output[0]['capacity'].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting data from API you can do anything you want.

For example, you can sum capacity with list comprehension.

```py
capacity = sum([x['capacity'] for x in output])
```

Or filter it like this

```py
filtered =  list(filter(lambda x: x['id'] ==1, output))
```

Pay attention, that you got list in your output.

Answer (score 1):

```
json = [{'id': 1, 'capacity': 5}, {'id': 2, 'capacity': 31}]

print(json[0]["capacity"])
```

Dicts have keys, you can reference them in squarebrackets!(`["capacity"]`) Also, this is a list, so you have to write `[0]` to get the element of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of dictionaries. Among other solutions, you could use

```
result = sum([x['capacity'] for x in output])
```

Answer (score 0):

Dict keys are indexed using `[]`, so for example:

```
foo = {"bar": 69}
print(foo["bar"])
```

Will print the number 69

Quick and easy way to sum all capacities, in your case, with a comprehension:

```
output = [{'id': 1, 'capacity': 5}, {'id': 2, 'capacity': 31}

total = sum(dictionary["capacity"] for dictionary in output)
```

Total is 36

Side note/tip, use **dict.get()** instead of **dict[]** to rather have `None` returned instead of an index error, for example:

```
# This will throw a KeyError
dictionary = {"foo": 69}
x = dictionary["baz"]

# This will return None
x = dictionary.get("baz")
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a list of dictionaries.  item is a dictionary with key value pair.

```
my_dict = [{'id': 1, 'capacity': 5}, {'id': 2, 'capacity': 31}]
for item in my_dict:
    print(item['capacity'])
```

output:

```
5,31
```